# salvage data from a failing drive

Tags: rsync, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a 6TB WD My Cloud sitting on the NW filled with data, I just got a 12TB WD My Book which I plugged into Rpi4, and began moving the data into the 12TB drive, planning to use the 6TB for backup only.

While copying the data via rsync, I saw that rsync got stuck on a single file.
Upon checking the logs I found the old 6TB drive is showing some issues.
I was able to copy a pretty big chunk of data (1.1TB) off of that drive before I ran into the issue, so I assume we are talking about bad sectors, not the whole drive dying immediately. I haven't ran any consistency checks on the data but it's not business critical. I have backups of my critical data, but I would like to recover as much as possible. The 6TB drive is currently unplugged, until I figure out the next steps.

I see a couple of ways I could move forward here:

1. just try to copy as much as possible to the 12TB drive, have rsync skip files it can't copy.
2. try to create a backup image of the 6TB drive via ddrescue to the 12TB (probably the longest process)
3. try to identify which files are corrupted and decide whether the long ddrescue process is worth it
   (found some info here but it seems like an extremely tedious process https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Identify_damaged_files#Ext2,_ext3,_and_ext4)

Now my questions would be:

1. rsync didn't actually throw any error, it just got stuck on the single file, I am not sure if there is a way for rsync to skip these files.
2. If I create an image via ddrescue, I would have to have the 6TB image on the 12TB drive, and then try to restore as much as possible onto the same drive. I am not sure how feasible this is. I assume that the ddrescue image creating would take *forever*, but then I should be able to copy the files from the mounted image to the same drive in normal speeds
3. Is there any tool that tries to read out all the files and would list the ones it can't read it their entirety? To me this sounds like the most time-saving approach.

Some logs from my 6TB drive for reference:

```
WDMyCloud6TB:/shares/Public# smartctl -l selftest /dev/sda4 
smartctl 5.41 2011-06-09 r3365 [armv7l-linux-3.2.26] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     28014         2321175776
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     28013         2321175776
# 3  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     28011         2321175776
# 4  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     28011         2321175776
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%         0         -
```

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR-K   188   188   051    -    444
  3 Spin_Up_Time            POS--K   189   188   021    -    9516
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   073   073   000    -    27858
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   200   200   140    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         -OSR-K   100   253   000    -    0
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   062   062   000    -    28014
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count -O--CK   100   253   000    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   100   100   000    -    31
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    17
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   191   191   000    -    27882
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   098   094   000    -    54
196 Reallocated_Event_Count -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--CK   200   200   000    -    1
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----CK   100   253   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -O--CK   200   200   000    -    0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   ---R--   100   253   000    -    0
```

```
WDMyCloud6TB:~# sudo fsck -v /dev/sda4
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sda4: clean, 128425/182996992 files, 1254382471/1463951872 blocks

WDMyCloud6TB:~# e2fsck -nv -b 32768 /dev/sda4
e2fsck 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
/dev/sda4 was not cleanly unmounted, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Killed
```

Comment: You've only got one Current_Pending_Sector, so that _could_ be the failed read that `rsync` found. Quick fix - just exclude that file. Failing that use `ddrescue`. It shouldn't take too long if most of the disk is good to read

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if a drive is failing (or suspected of failing), it's always a good idea to try recovering files from it using an image copy of the drive rather than the drive itself.  So, use `ddrescue` to make an image, and/or optionally use `qemu-img convert` to turn it into a compressed qcow2 image to save disk space. Then mount it as a loop device (or and NBD device with qemu-nbd), and rsync the files from the mounted image.    The image file could be saved on the 12TB drive but performance will be greatly improved if you have another drive big enough to hold it.

Comment: thanks for the comments. @roaima you were actually right, I ended up moving everything out via rsync as it was a single file/sector that was corrupted. thanks again